# Как получить адрес без ненужных полей с помощью Yandex MapKit

Tags: android, kotlin, yandexmapkit

Хочу получить адрес без страны и области, в [Поиск в MapKit: Tips & Tricks](https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/428564/) есть пример как выбрать город,

```kotlin
val city = response.collection.children.firstOrNull()?.obj
    ?.metadataContainer
    ?.getItem(ToponymObjectMetadata::class.java)
    ?.address
    ?.components
    ?.firstOrNull { it.kinds.contains(Address.Component.Kind.LOCALITY) }
    ?.name
```

но что если мне нужен весь адрес, но без страны и области.

У меня получилось вот так:

```kotlin
                val requiredAddress = geoObject
                    .metadataContainer
                    .getItem(ToponymObjectMetadata::class.java)
                    ?.address
                    ?.components
                    ?.map {
                        if (!it.kinds.contains(Address.Component.Kind.COUNTRY)) {
                            if (!it.kinds.contains(Address.Component.Kind.PROVINCE)) {
                                it.name
                            } else {
                                ""
                            }
                        } else {
                            ""
                        }
                    }
```

но в итоге я получаю пустые значения в начале списка, например:

```
[, , , Всеволожский район, Всеволожское городское поселение, Всеволожск, микрорайон Южный, Знаменская улица, 14]
```

которые надо удалять.
Либо надо отдельно брать каждое поле и добавлять их поочередно к строке.

Нет ли способа сделать это красивее и лаконичнее?

Answer (score 1):

В коде вместо удаления значений вы проставляете пустые строки, поэтому получается такой массив c пустыми значениями в начале на выходе.

Ниже привел исправленную версию кода, убрав блоки кода, где выполняется условие (страна или область).

```kotlin
val requiredAddress = geoObject
  .metadataContainer
  .getItem(ToponymObjectMetadata::class.java)
  ?.address
  ?.components
  ?.map {
    if (!it.kinds.contains(Address.Component.Kind.COUNTRY) &&
        !it.kinds.contains(Address.Component.Kind.PROVINCE)) {
      it.name
    }
  }
```

Comment: Если сделать как вы написали то возвращаемый тип будет List<Unit>?, пустые строки я проставляю для того чтобы возвращаемый тип элемента списка был не нулабельный - List<String>?.
В принципе можно сделать и нулабельный всё равно потом запускаю фильтр пустых значений.